# Compute $E[S_n\mid T_1+\cdots+T_n\leq w<T_1+\cdots+T_{n+1}]$, where $S_n=\sup\{T_1,r\}+\cdots+\sup\{T_n,r\}$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $(T_i)$ denote a sequence of iid exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$, $r$ some constant, and, for every $i$, $X_i=\sup\{T_i,r\}$.
How to compute $$E[X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n\mid T_1+\cdots+T_n\leq w<T_1+\cdots +T_{n+1}]$$ for some given $w$?

I was able to find an expression for this if $X_i$ is simply an exponential random variable, but am having trouble if $X_i$ is as defined above.

Comment: By $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ i.i.d. do you mean $X_1\mid T=t,\cdots,X_n\mid T=t$ i.i.d. for any $t$?

Comment: I think I did not define the rvs properly. Does the edit clear that up?

Comment: Please refer to the edited version of your question, and try to mimick it for your further questions on the site.

Comment: Apologies for the poorly worded question. The posted answer made me realize I had made another mistake in defining the expectation. The edit changes it from the question that was originally posted, but I wasn't sure if I should ask a new question, so am sticking with the edit for now.

Answer (score 2):

$X_n$'s are independent. Hence conditioning on $\{X_{n+1} >w\}$ has no effect. So the value is $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i |X_n \leq w)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} EX_i+E(X_n|X_n \leq w)$. I suppose you can take it from here.

Comment: Your answer made me realize I did not correctly define the expectation that I was trying to compute. I have made an edit but that changes the question from the one you originally answered. My apologies for that.